# File is already use in some other process

Tags: c#, .net

Here I want to delete  line in a textfiles  containg  specific string like "21309#003" where item1 is a filename but It shows runtime exception that item1 (file) is already use in some process.How I Solve this problem.I am new in .net C#.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<String>().ToList();
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(item);


        }


        foreach (var item1 in selectedItems)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(item1);
            string line = null;
            //string line_to_delete = "the line i want to delete";

           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(item1))
            //item1=  "C:\\IMP2711\\textpresent.txt"
            {

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(item1))
                {
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                        //if (String.Compare(line, @"*21349#003*") == 0)

                       //if (!line.Contains("21349#003") )
                       if (!line.StartsWith("21349#003"))
                       {**strong text**

                           writer.WriteLine(line);
                       }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: well of course it's in use, you're reading from it at the same time as writing to it (var item2 = item1 - same file isn't it?).  Write the file to another name file name (i.e. string item2 = item1 + ".tmp"), delete the original and rename it copy to the old name when done.  (File.Delete(), File.Move()).  [And use string if it's known to be a string, not var - that's just being lazy.]

Comment: @Ankit Gupta: You also have another problem: You are removing the selected items from the listbox twice: Once in each foreach.

Comment: Just read the file, then write to it after it's been read. No need to have a using statement nested in another. Espcially if it's using the same thing.

Comment: Hi Rob still when I an deleting the file "item1" it shows the same run time exception,that is file already in use.Suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 4):

You are reading and writing to the same file at the same time.

```
var item2 = item1;
```

If the file is not to big you can read the lines into memory and then write the lines you want to keep back to the file. We can even simplify your code a little bit.

```
File.WriteAllLines(item1, 
    File.ReadLines(item1).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("21349#003")).ToList());
```

Another option if the file is very large is to write to a temporary file. Delete the original and then rename the temporary.

```
var tmp = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllLines(tmp, File.ReadLines(item1).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("21349#003")));
File.Delete(item1);
File.Move(tmp, item1);
```

Comment: Hi bob, I have edited the code Please see once. I have removed the extra var Item2 but its not working yet.

Comment: @AnkitGupta The problem is the same, you can not read and write to a file at the same time. First read the lines you want, close the file and then open it again and write the lines. Or use a temporary file that you rename afterwards and delete the original.

Comment: "Not working" is a little bit vague. Same error as before?

Comment: Getting error "System.IO.ReadLines  does not contain a definition for ReadLines"

Comment: You must be using a very old version of the framework. But you can change it to: `File.WriteAllLines(item1, 
File.ReadAllLines(item1).Where(l => !l.StartsWith("21349#003")));`

Comment: hi Magnus Problem Solved Now. Many Thanks to You

Answer (score 0):

If your file is small first read it to memory and then try to write on it, you have two stream on the same file, a file can share between multiple streams but you can not modify a file when it is open by another stream,  if your file is huge and you can not moved to memory you can create a temp file and write to temp file when your reading finished replacing original file with temp file and removing temp file.

Answer (score -2):

There's some process that's locking the file `c:\imp2711\textpresent.txt`. You have to find and kill it.

To find it out, please refer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: Look at the code!, he's reading the same file himself - this process has locked it - no need to look anywhere else.

Comment: One should not answer when too busy :-|